# To find the number of possible continuous function

Tags: definite-integrals

What are the number of possible continuous functions $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ for which
$$ I_1 = \int_0^1 f(x)dx=1,\\
I_2 =\int_0^1 xf(x)dx =a,\\
I_3 = \int_0^1 x^2f(x)dx=a^2.$$
I have no idea how to to solve it.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add limits in integral. In each integral the limit is from 0 to 1

Comment: Feel free to add the limits.

Comment: @EugenCovaci please give some hint to solve it

Comment: Are you sure there are no more conditions? As posed, there are infinite functions such that $\int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm{d}x = 1$

Comment: The question is correct and the answer is zero.

Comment: @EugenCovaci  there is no such function possible which statisfy the given condtions

Comment: @Anaedonist there are no more condtions are given. The answer in my book is zero.

Comment: Is there also a condition like $f\geq 0$?

Comment: @Rigel the question is complete. No other conditions are given

Comment: The answer is zero? I am well puzzled..Try the function $f(x) = 2x$, integrate between $0$ and $1$...

Comment: @Anaedonist if f(x) =2x then it satisfy only first integral and after that third intagral will not be the square of second integral

Comment: @Anaedonist $f(x) = 2x$ is not a counterexample

Comment: Indeed, I slowly understood all the conditions are to apply simultaneously, my apologies

Comment: @Anaedonist its ok.. please help me to solve it. No idea from where and how to star it?

Answer (score 6):

Without a condition on the sign of the function, you can find a continuous $f$ satisfying all conditions.
Namely, it is enough to choose
$$
f(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma
$$
and to find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ by solving the (uniquely solvable) linear system obtained imposing the three conditions.
(The solution should be $\alpha = (6a^2-6a+1)/30$, $\beta = -180 a^2 +192 a -36$, $\gamma = 30 a^2 - 36 a + 9$.)

On the other hand, there are no continuous functions satisfying $f\geq 0$ or $f\leq 0$ and the three given conditions.
Indeed, one has
$$
\int_0^1 (x-a)^2 f(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 x^2 f(x)\, dx - 2a \int_0^1 x f(x)\, dx
+ a^2 \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0,
$$
but the unique continuous function $f\geq 0$ (or $f\leq 0$) satisfying this condition is $f\equiv 0$, that clearly does not satisfy the first requirement.

Comment: can we choose any type of function instead of quadratic.

Comment: Note that the case $f(x)\leq 0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ is impossible since $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = 1 > 0$.

Comment: @Harry49 how can you say that f<0 for given interval is impossible. Can you  explain it. Please

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora Yes, it's a theorem: the integral of a negative function is negative. Therefore, $f$ cannot be negative all over $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

One may exploit the fact that [shifted Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) provide an orthogonal base of $L^2(0,1)$ with respect to the standard inner product. The given constraints lead to
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)P_0(2x-1)\,dx = 1,\quad \int_{0}^{1}P_1(2x-1)\,dx=2a-1$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)P_2(2x-1)\,dx=6a^2-6a+1 $$
hence any function of the form
$$ 1+(6a-3)P_1(2x-1)+(30a^2-30a+5)P_2(2x-1)+\sum_{m\geq 3}c_m P_m(2x-1) $$
does the job. However, if we assume $a\geq 0$ and further impose $f(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,1]$ we get the unique solution $f(x)\equiv 0$ associated to $a=0$, since the constraints ensure we are in the equality case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ \left(\int_{0}^{1} x f(x)\,dx\right)^2\leq \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx \int_{0}^{1}x^2 f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: I didnt got your Cauchy schwartz inequality

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora: write $x\,f(x)$ as $x\sqrt{f(x)}\cdot\sqrt{f(x)}$. Is it clear now?

Comment: I got cauchy schwartz inequlaity. But i am ug student so i am unable to understand your answer. It will be helpful for me if u explain by other method or in detail

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora: let $a,b$ non-negative, square-integrable functions over $(0,1)$. If $$\left(\int_{0}^{1}a(x)b(x)\,dx\right)^2 = \int_{0}^{1}a(x)^2\,dx \int_{0}^{1}b(x)^2\,dx $$ holds, then $\frac{a}{b}$ is almost-everywhere constant on $(0,1)$. In your case, $x\sqrt{f(x)}=\lambda\sqrt{f(x)}$ implies $f\equiv 0$ a.e. on $(0,1)$, hence $f\equiv 0$ since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: In our question how are u sure that f(x) >0 for x belongs to [0,1]?

Comment: The first part of my answer does not assume that. The second part of my answer states that **if** we assume $f(x)\geq 0$ on $[0,1]$, **then**...

Comment: What would happen if f(x)<0 for given interval,

Comment: Then $a$ would be negative.

Comment: Uptil now i only have concept of  cauch schwartz inequality and i got only your last step...thanks for explaining . If u explain by other method except legendre polynomial then i will definitly got it.

Comment: . In our case, $x\sqrt{f(x)}=\lambda\sqrt{f(x)}$ implies either $\sqrt{f(x)}=0 or \x-\lambda=0$. Why we cant take $x= \lambda$

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora: the only non negative **function** that for some $\lambda$ ensures $x\sqrt{f(x)}=\lambda\sqrt{f(x)}$ for **any** $x\in(0,1)$ is the zero function.

Comment: Thnks a lot for explaining. But i am still stuck by f(x)<0 or f(x) >0 . As we assumes f(x) >0 for given interval so we can apply schwartz equlality. If f(x)<0 for some sub interval then how we can do

Comment: If you have $f(x)\leq 0$ on $[0,1]$ and $a\leq 0$ then by renaming $f(x)$ as $-f(x)$ and $a$ as $-a$ you are in the same situation outlined by the second part of my answer. So, for short, if $a\neq 0$ and $f(x)$ is $\geq 0$ or $\leq 0$ on $[0,1]$, then $f\equiv 0$. If we allow $f(x)$ to change its sign on $[0,1]$, there are plenty of solutions for any value of $a$, see the first part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I think i will get it only after reading the concept of legendre.